# Is it possible to count how many fields are in .addFields() from a MessageEmbed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I know it is possible to `.spliceFields()`, as long as I indicate the index and the number of fields to delete. But since I have many embeds and I want them to splice every single field from one main embed, I'd like to create a variable with a value equal to the number of fields from the main embed, because I may add more fields into it in the future.

Here's an example of what I have:

```js
const mainEmbed = new MessageEmbed().addFields({
  name: 'HUDs',
  value: '\u200B',
});

const hudEmbed = new MessageEmbed(mainEmbed).spliceFields(0, 1, [
  { name: 'Black', value: `¤${items.huds.black.price}`, inline: true },
  { name: 'Blue', value: `¤${items.huds.blue.price}`, inline: true },
  { name: 'Brown', value: `¤${items.huds.brown.price}`, inline: true },
  { name: 'Green', value: `¤${items.huds.green.price}`, inline: true },
  { name: 'Orange', value: `¤${items.huds.orange.price}`, inline: true },
  { name: 'Pink', value: `¤${items.huds.pink.price}`, inline: true },
  { name: 'Purple', value: `¤${items.huds.purple.price}`, inline: true },
  { name: 'Red', value: `¤${items.huds.red.price}`, inline: true },
  { name: 'Yellow', value: `¤${items.huds.yellow.price}`, inline: true },
]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`MessageEmbed#fields`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed?scrollTo=fields) property.

```js
mainEmbed.fields.length
```

Comment: No problem; sorry I got the name of the embed wrong 